# C++: Read in data from file to populate Linked List

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am trying to take a .dat file that has 8 lines, the first being the number of records and the remaining 7 lines consist of the data for the records that will populate the linked list.

The problem I am running into is that my code is only populating the first record but using cout I know that it is going through the entire file. Here is the snippet of code that I'm working with:

```
fstream listBuilder;
listBuilder.open("HW06.dat");

if ( listBuilder.is_open() ) {
    TeleType *current;
    current = listHead;

    listBuilder >> numberOfRecords;

    while ( listBuilder ) {
        string firstName;
        string lastName;
        string phone;
        string name;

        listBuilder >> firstName >> lastName >> phone;

        name = firstName + " " + lastName;
        current->name = name;
        current->number = phone;

        current = current->nextaddr;
        current = new TeleType;
    }

    listBuilder.close();
} // end if
else {
    cout << "***** Error: File failed to open. *****" << endl;
} // end else
```

Comment: To make a linked list work you need to link the nodes. Doesn't look like you are doing that.

Comment: As opposed to just using a `List<string` or `Slist<String>` and appending?  It is very strange doing a C-style list build with C++ semantics.  Failing that, you have not given all your code.  `listHead`? `TeleType`? Also, if you are sure of the input from `numberOfRecords`, you could for loop on that.

Comment: Drawing boxes and arrows on paper is the best way to debug code with pointers.

Answer (score 1):

You should first create the next node and then point to it, not the other way around!!

```
current->nextaddr = new TeleType; 
current = current->nextaddr;
```

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly my issue!